Number of vertices in a hexagon made of equilateral triangles
During my engineering project, I ran into a problem. I have a hexagon made of equilateral triangles so that each side of the hexagon contains the base of 43 triangles (the length of each side of the hexagon is $n=42$ times the length of each side of a triangle). Each vertex of a triangle is equivalent to a "tube". For instance, in the below figure, $n=2$ (3 tubes on 1 side) and there are 19 tubes.

One of my professors asked me how I could know I had exactly drawn the correct number of tubes (5419 tubes).
Can anyone help me find the number of vertices in a hexagon made of equilateral triangles in this case, or more general, if $n$ varies?
Thanks in advance!

You would have number of vertices - number of edges + number of triangles = 1

Your question is not very well posed. First of all, how exactly is the parameter $n$ defined? And what is the value of $n$ in the example of your photograph? On top of that, your photograph has some irregularities: along the six "sides" of your hexagon, five sides have four tubes and the sixth side has three tubes; is that something we should just ignore and pretend that the sixth side has four tubes?

Thanks for your comment, I have edited the post. I intended to put a real image but they have some irregularities that cause confusion. I have changed the figure into drawings instead.
My first guess is that for each half of the hexagon, each row has 1 more tube than its previous row.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_hexagonal_number

Start from the single center tube and grow out in rings. The first ring has 6 tubes and for each following step you are adding a hexagonal ring in which each edge has 1 more tube than its predecessor. Thus the total number of tubes when each edge of the hexagon has $n$ tubes is
$$f(n) = 1 + 6 \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = 1 + 3(n-1)n = 3n^2 - 3n + 1.$$
This can also be seen by constructing the hexagon with $n$ tubes on a side as follows. Around a central tube, wrap six equilateral triangles of with $n-1$ tubes per side, alternately base down and apex down. The number of tubes in each of these triangles is of course
$$1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-1) = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}.$$
Since there are six such triangles, that's another way to see that
$$f(n) = 1 + 3(n-1)n.$$
In your example, where the length of a side is 42, there are $n=43$ tubes on a side, and the formula does indeed give $f(43) = 5419$ tubes.

He was asking for the number of vertices no? Not the number of triangles

I've edited my answer, @julio_es_sui_glace, to clarify the meaning (and tweak the value of $n$).

For the number of vertices, you begin with « a point », then by adding 6 triangles you get an hexagon, and there is exactly one vertex added on each side of the hexagon.
Now if you continue adding hexagons to get a 2-large hexagon, you will add 2 vertices by side ($6 \times 2$ in total).
For a three-large hexagon you’ll add 3 vertices by side, etc
This gives you for a $n$-large hexagon the number of vertices:
$$v(n) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n 6i = 1 + 6\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 3n^2 + 3n +1$$
with the convention that a $0$-large hexagon is just a point.
A similar reasoning gives you the number of faces:
$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n 6 \cdot(1 +2(i-1)) = 6 \cdot (-n + n(n+1)) = 6n^2$$
Since the Euler characteristic of a filled hexagon is 1 (it is contractible), you get:
$$v(n)-e(n)+f(n) = 1$$
Where $e$ is the number of edges, so we deduce that there is
$$e(n) = v(n)+f(n)-1 = 9n^2 +3n$$
edges.
